# Multiplayer game programming

Tags: android, network-programming, multiplayer

I'm working on a game where multiple players should be able to play at a time. It's a `2D` game, and all the characters should be able to see each other move on the screen.
Like the game is now all the devices just post and fetch each others `coordinates` to a server. This is done by running to threads:

```
public void StartCoordinatorFetcherThread(final Sprite Object)
{
    Thread CoordinateStarter = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {           
            while(true)
            {
                Object.testing = Object.InternetObject.GetMessages();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    CoordinateStarter.start();
}

public void StartCoordinatorPosterThread(final Sprite Object)
{
    Thread CoordinatePoster = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {           
            while(true)
            {
                Object.InternetObject.PostCoordinates(Object.x,Object.y);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    CoordinatePoster.start();
}
```

Anyway, I would like the characters to move more smoothly since it can be a bit `"laggy"` doing it like this.Does anyone have an idea on how I can achieve this goal?

Maybe I should I have a type of coordinate stack which just gets pushed coordinates to it all the time and then pops of the values as the game runs?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out linear interpolation / extrapolation methods to help smooth out the movement. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

here are some resources on how to implement many of the numerical algorithms in practice
http://www.nr.com/

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, looks like linear interpolation can help out. Found an example on that http://www.racer.nl/tech/multiplayer.html

Comment: How does this idea sound:
I'm using linear interpolation and determine how many frames it should move for each time the screen updates. Hence, if (I'll only focus on the X-coordinate for this example) the previous coordinate was 40 (the location the character has on the screen now), the current is 60 (where the character should move to), and the frameupdate interval is 5 coordinates for each update. This means that I'll get 4 (4*5) updates before the character has reached 60. So I'll only add this moves to an eventlist for the given character and the "laggy" part will be virtually gone :)

Comment: Basically this is a process of processing previous data (interpolation) and guessing what will happen before the next set of  data is received (extrapolation). If the network refresh rate is 10 FPS and your update loop is 60 FPS you have to extrapolate (guess) the 5 points taking in account the previous movement so you get smooth traversal lines. When you get the next point from network, you do the interpolation of the actual data on previous set of points and then again extrapolate (guess) the next 5 points, and so on. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I understand what you are telling me :) But I guess I have to rewrite my code in that case since my way of thinking is wrong then :-/

Comment: I strongly recommend looking into cubic spline interpolation if you can store/access first-order partial derivatives (iow, velocity) from the current and last "ticks".  I use this in a galaxy-simulator and it looks fantastic even when rendering 50 frames per tick.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is flash, but this is a nice tutorial to improve the move of players:
http://playerio.com/documentation/tutorials/building-flash-multiplayer-games-tutorial/

Comment: Good reference as well, I highly recommend it!